# How to undo "mkswap"?

Tags: swap

I had a problem with mysql and I needed to make a swap file to fix it. I ran this code

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap.dat bs=1024 count=512M
# mkswap /swap.dat
# swapon /swap.dat
## Edit the /etc/fstab, and the following entry.
/swap.dat      none    swap    sw      0       0
```

It makes a swap file, of 512mb I think. Now my VPS says I'm using 99.9% of 19.56gb.

I tried to run `swapoff /swap.dat` and remove `/swap.dat` from /etc/fstab but it still says I'm using 99.9%

I can't install any additional software like gparted because it says that the device has no space left

Comment: Try rebooting and see if that fixes is

Comment: @CollDue96 I already did it. :(

Comment: You had created a file that is 1024 * 512MB in size, have you checked that with ls -l? You also didn't say if you have deleted /swap.dat or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, remove that entry from `/etc/fstab`.  Then:

```
sudo swapoff /swap.dat
# Wait for all resources paged to that swap file to be moved to other swap files or to RAM.
sudo rm -f /swap.dat
```

If you remove the file before it is no longer in use, the disk space will remain allocated until `swapoff` is complete.